# Solutions/General Properties of a Special Polynomial

Tags: polynomials, symmetric-polynomials

(From a problem in statistical physics) I'm trying to find the general properties of solutions (i.e., possible values of $t_0$) to the equation 
$$1 = \sum_{\ell=1}^{N} \frac{1}{x_{\ell} + t_0},$$
which can alternatively be written as the $N$th order polynomial
$$ \prod_{\ell=1}^{N} (x_{\ell} + t_0) - \sum_{j=1}^{N} \sum_{i\neq j}^{N} (x_i + t_0) = 0$$
where $x_j\geq 0$ for all $j$. 
Because this equation can be written as an $N$th order polynomial, the fundamental theorem of algebra assures us that it has $N$ complex roots. That is, the two equations, can be reduced to 
\begin{equation}
\prod^{N}_{m=1} \Big[ q_{m}(\{x_{\ell}\}) - t_0\Big] = 0, 
\end{equation}
where $q_{m}(\{x_{\ell}\}) = q_{m}(x_1, \ldots, x_{N})$ are the (possibly complex) roots of the given polynomial.

**My (more specific) question:** If $x_{\ell} \geq 0$ for all $\ell$, what are the properties (if any) of the solutions $q_{\ell}(\{x_i\})$? For example, are there general conditions when they're exclusively real?

(Also will appreciate if someone can point me to a reference that deals with problems like this)

Comment: It's not too clear what general properties you are looking for, but may be worth noting that if $P(t)=\prod_{k=1}^N (t+x_k)$ then the given equation is equivalent to $P'(t_0) / P(t_0) = 1\,$.

Comment: Yes, I know that. The above condition was actually derived from minimizing $G(t) = - t+  \ln P(t)$.

The properties I'm looking for are something like whether we could say if the roots are real or not.